# My code in server express for seo stuff react-app hasn't work as expected, what im doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, seo, server-side-rendering

I made an express server for my react application, for seo optimization. I need to dynamically substitute meta tags in order to make the preview of the post look attractive when I post it on social networks. Inside the router, I make a get request via axios to the backend to get data from a specific post, and then from the received response I pull out the data from the required fields and put it in meta tags. In order to replace old data that is not fresh, I made temporary variables with data for meta tags and after a new request, temporary data is replaced with new ones and so on in a circle. My code is not working as I expect, what could be the problem? Is there a way to store temporary variables right inside the index file or do I need to make a temporary storage?

right down my index.js file:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const  path =   require('path');
const express =  require('express');
const fs = require('fs');


const baseUrl = 'https://itnews.pro/pre/api';
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.MIDDLEWARE_EXPRESS_PORT || 8084;
const indexPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html');

let tempMainTitle = 'IT-NEWS';
let tempMetaTitle = '__META_OG_TITLE__';
let tempMetaUrl = '__META_OG_URL__';
let tempMetaCover = '__META_OG_IMAGE__';
let tempMetaDescription = '__META_OG_DESCRIPTION__';

let mainTitle = '';
let metaTitle = '';
let metaUrl = '';
let metaCover = '';
let metaDescription = '';

app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {

    let urlForRequest = `${baseUrl + "/publication/objects" + req.url.replace('/news/', "/").replace("/events/", "/") + "?format=json"}`;

    if (req.url.includes('news') || req.url.includes('events') || req.url.includes('arcticles')) {
       axios.get(urlForRequest)
        .then((a_res) => {

            //settings data for meta tags
            mainTitle = a_res?.data?.title;
            metaTitle = a_res?.data?.title;
            metaUrl = baseUrl + a_res?.data?.id_full;
            metaCover = baseUrl + a_res?.data?.cover;
            metaDescription = a_res?.data?.short_content.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '');

            //cahce variable for replacing in the future with new data
            tempMetaTitle = a_res?.data?.title;
            tempMetaUrl = baseUrl + a_res?.data?.id_full;
            tempMetaCover = baseUrl + a_res?.data?.cover;
            tempMetaDescription = a_res?.data?.short_content.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '');
            tempMainTitle = a_res?.data?.title

            return res.data;

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("cant fetch data from expres: ", err);
        })
        .finally((console.log("Ooops")))
    }

    fs.readFile(indexPath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error during file reading', err);
            return res.status(404).end()
        }
        htmlData = htmlData.replace(`<title>${tempMainTitle}</title>`, `<title>${mainTitle}</title>`)
        .replace(tempMetaTitle, metaTitle)
        .replace('__META_OG_TYPE__', 'article')
        .replace(tempMetaDescription, metaDescription)
        .replace(tempMetaCover, metaCover)
        .replace(tempMetaUrl, metaUrl);

        return res.send(htmlData);
    });
});

//path to static that will be rendered
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('Error during app startup', error);
    }
    console.log("listening on " + PORT + "...");
});
```

I tried to make the request and reading from the file asynchronous and it didn't help.